# bootstrap 3 nav bar toggle not displaying anything on click

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3

I know this seems to be a common problem for people and I've read as much as I can find on the matter, but I have missed something. I followed the example on the bootstrap site as a template, the site is responsive and resizes like it should. When it hits the point that the toggle button is displayed, I click and nothing happens. This is on a master page

Head HTML:

```
<head runat="server"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<link href="../Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="../Content/Interior.css" rel="stylesheet" /> <!-- custom style sheet -->
<link href="../Content/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
```

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Site Name</a>
                </div>

                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="#">Dash</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Edit Profile</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Invite</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Record A Message</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <p class="navbar-text">Connections <span class="badge">0</span></p>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li>
                            <p class="navbar-text">Sign out as <a class="navbar-link" href="Login.aspx">User</a></p>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
...
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'd appreciate any ideas on the matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add a period on this line:

`<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">`

(ended up putting this together to figure it out: http://jsfiddle.net/VDcnr/)

Although I would recommend placing a custom class there for the odd corner case that you end up having two nav bars on the same page.

Also, as a sidenote, I'm pretty sure normalize.css is included in bootstrap, so you shouldn't need to include it again.

Comment: Right as I read your first line, I knew what I had left out. Argh. Good eye there.